# Stripe checkout redirect automatic to Stripe page on iphone

Tags: iphone, stripe-payments

I use Stripe checkout for payment process. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom
On desktop it view normal popup.
And on Iphone with Chrome browser, it show popup normal too.
But on Iphone with Safari browser it redirect to Stripe home page,

1. [image]
   I go setting and disable "Block popup" but issues till happen.

Please help me show popup checkout normal at safari on iphone.

2. And another problem.

When I access from Vietnam IP. Button pay not show **USD** before money.
But with customer access from Australia, this button show **USD**.

Please help me hide **USD** from Stripe submit button.

3. With issues from Australia too.
   As config bellow , I add *allowRememberMe* in Stripe config, When access from VietNam I see this option at checkbox, but access from Australia customer can't see it.

Please help me show option *Remember me* when access from Australia too.

Thanks all. 
This is code config.

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'xxx',
    image: '{{ asset("home/images/madpaws-logo-payment.png") }}',
    locale: 'auto',
    allowRememberMe: true,
    token: function(token) {
        //: After payment success => update status booking
        if(token.id){
            //: Code process here.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add more relevant tags. I had to fully read your question to understand that it has nothing to do with mobile iOS development.